# Why should max(balance) be used when looking at current balance for each account? SQL interview question

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I've been asked the question
**'Why do you need to use the max function on the balance column to get the current balance for each account?'**
for the following query example:

```
SELECT
    universe -- (bookmaker name)
    ,wallet_id
    ,sum(operator_balance_delta) as profit
    ,max(balance) as current_balance 
    
FROM 
    transactions
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  
            id
            ,universe
            ,balance
        FROM 
            wallets -- (accounts table)
        WHERE 
            created_at BETWEEN '2021-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-02-01 00:00:00'
            AND currency = 'GBP'
            AND last_bet_at IS NOT NULL
            AND balance >= 0
            LIMIT 100
    ) AS accounts ON accounts.id = transactions.wallet_id

WHERE type_id IN (SELECT id FROM transaction_types WHERE code IN ('bet','casino-wager','virtualsports-wager','live-casino-wager','bingo-wager'))    
GROUP BY wallet_id,type_id,universe
```

As far as I can tell the maximum would just give, as the name suggests, the maximum balance of an account and not necessarily the current balance. The only thing that I thought could be the case, is if somehow the max is taking into consideration the date and therefore returning the balance at max(date), or in other words the current balance.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: . . The logic looks incorrect to me.  That would make this a "trick" question.

Comment: Oh really?! Is that common practise for technical tests? It has left stumped for a couple days.

Comment: The better response should be: why does this query not follow best practices and use aliases for each table and qualify every column reference with the correct alias. But for any question of this nature, one needs to know schema and understand how it is used. That is not provided here. SQL Server does not support LIMIT either - so something smells here. And the terms / columns "current balance" and balance are not clear at all. Applying MAX to some sort of balance column seems like a kludge to overcome a logic fault in the query IMO.

Comment: I don't think trick questions are very common but I often ask open-ended questions to ascertain candidates knowledge. If the interview is for Microsoft SQL Server (as suggested by the `sql-server` tag), I would first call out  `LIMIT` is invalid  syntax.

Comment: I think what I may do in that case is re-write the query to search for what I think their target is, and then present that with my answers to the other questions.

Comment: It won't give the maximum balance, because the `balance` column comes from the `wallet` table (in other words the current balance). It should really be part of the `group by`, then it doesn't require aggregation. `created_at BETWEEN` is also probably wrong, it should use a half-open interval `created_at >= ... AND created_at < ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to use aggregation here because the `balance` column is not part of the `GROUP BY`.** Any column not in the `GROUP BY` must have an aggregation.

`max(balance)` does *not* give you the maximum balance of the account, because the `balance` column comes from the `wallet` table, not the `transaction` table. Since `wallet_id` is part of the `GROUP BY`, and `balance` is functionally dependent on it, there will only be one `balance` value.

**What should really happen here is that `balance` should be in the `GROUP BY`.** Alternatively, the `transaction` table should be pre-grouped in a subquery.

**Further issues with this query as presented:**

- Table aliases should be used, and columns should have a reference to the table they come from
- `created_at BETWEEN ...` is probably wrong, as it includes the end point. It should use a half-open interval `created_at >= ... AND created_at < ...`
- The subquery `type_id IN (SELECT ...` is not necessary and could be a normal join, because `id` is a primary key
- `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` will give indeterminate results

So the final query would look like this, if I was writing it:

```sql
SELECT
    w.universe -- (bookmaker name)
    ,w.id as wallet_id
    ,sum(t.operator_balance_delta) as profit
    ,w.balance as current_balance 
    
FROM 
    transactions t
JOIN
    (
        SELECT  
            w.id
            ,w.universe
            ,w.balance
        FROM 
            wallets w -- (accounts table)
        WHERE 
            w.created_at >= '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
            AND w.created_at < '2021-02-01 00:00:00'
            AND w.currency = 'GBP'
            AND w.last_bet_at IS NOT NULL
            AND w.balance >= 0
        ORDER BY balance DESC
        LIMIT 100
    ) AS a ON a.id = t.wallet_id

JOIN transaction_types tt
  ON tt.type_id = t.id
  AND tt.code IN (
      'bet',
      'casino-wager',
      'virtualsports-wager',
      'live-casino-wager',
      'bingo-wager')
GROUP BY
  w.id,
  w.universe,
  w.balance,
  t.type_id;
```